# How to Update field using subquery with aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Update query that will help me to update a certain field and right now it is throwing an error on the last two lines of code where the d.column is mentioned. Does anyone know how I can still use the d.column fields at the end or know a work around that will produce the same results? Help is greatly appreciated. The error is where I am using d.LastUpdateSchedule and d.Due_Dte  in the last two lines of code.

```
   update ods.Customer
  set NumberTPD = a.NumberCode
  from ods.Customer r
  left join
   (
Select d.CustomerNumber
    , d.due_Dte
    , l.NumberCode
     from (select r.CustomerNumber
       , r.due_Dte
        , r.NumberTPD
        , max(l.UpdateSchedule) as LastUpdateSchedule
      from ods.Customer r
        left join ods.CustomerHistory l
         on r.CustomerNumber = l.CustomerNumber
         and r.due_Dte >= l.UpdateSchedule
         and l.Examine = 1 
         and r.ExamineFrequency in ('MONTHLY','MNTHLYLDAY')
         and isnull(r.ScheduleEndDate,'1970-01-01') < r.due_Dte
        group by r.CustomerNumber, r.Due_Dte, r.NumberTPD) d
   left join ods.CustomerHistory l
   on d.CustomerNumber = l.CustomerNumber
  and d.LastUpdateSchedule = l.UpdatedSchedule
) a
     on r.CustomerNumber = a.CustomerNumber
     and r.Due_Dte = a.Due_Dte
       where d.Due_Dte > '2018-08-03'
      and d.LastUpdateSchedule is not null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because your `table d` is inside your `table a` move your `where` clause to `table d`

```
update ods.Customer
set NumberTPD = a.NumberCode
from ods.Customer r
left join
    (Select d.CustomerNumber
        , d.due_Dte
        , l.NumberCode

    from 
        (select r.CustomerNumber
            , r.due_Dte
            , r.NumberTPD
            , max(l.UpdateSchedule) as LastUpdateSchedule
        from ods.Customer r
        left join ods.CustomerHistory l on r.CustomerNumber = l.CustomerNumber
            and r.due_Dte >= l.UpdateSchedule
            and l.Examine = 1 
            and r.ExamineFrequency in ('MONTHLY','MNTHLYLDAY')
            and isnull(r.ScheduleEndDate,'1970-01-01') < r.due_Dte
        group by r.CustomerNumber, r.Due_Dte, r.NumberTPD) d
    left join ods.CustomerHistory l on d.CustomerNumber = l.CustomerNumber
        and d.LastUpdateSchedule = l.UpdatedSchedule
    where d.Due_Dte > '2018-08-03'
    and d.LastUpdateSchedule is not null
    ) a on r.CustomerNumber = a.CustomerNumber
            and r.Due_Dte = a.Due_Dte
```

Comment: @Metal will this pull the same result as if it was on the outside. The reason I had it on the outside is because I wanted to use it with the left join coming from the outside. with it being on the inside and still being with a left join would this produce the same result?

Comment: yes, it should produce same result, because there's a correlation between your customer numbers.

Comment: @Metal so for some reason It is only updating NumberTPD for dates that are  greater than Due_Dte with a value of  '2018-08-03' do you know why it would be setting all the values in that field before that date to null? is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: you are using left join, that's why its setting up the due dates to null, if you only want to update based on your subquery result, should be using inner join

Comment: @metal So you think just using an inner join on the outside will fix it and keep the left joins on the inside?

Comment: left join will result null values. so for customers that does'nt have any customerhistory, it will be included on the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- only what you need

UPDATE cust
SET cust.NumberTPD = histRow.NumberCode
FROM ods.Customer cust
JOIN
  (SELECT c.CustomerNumber,
          max(h.UpdateSchedule) AS LastUpdateSchedule
   FROM ods.Customer c
   JOIN ods.CustomerHistory h ON c.CustomerNumber = h.CustomerNumber
   AND c.due_Dte >= h.UpdateSchedule
   WHERE c.Due_Dte > '2018-08-03'
     AND c.ExamineFrequency IN ('MONTHLY',
                                'MNTHLYLDAY')
     AND isnull(c.ScheduleEndDate, '1970-01-01') < c.due_Dte --sure about this?

     AND h.Examine = 1
   GROUP BY c.CustomerNumber) maxes
JOIN ods.CustomerHistory histRow ON maxes.CustomerNumber = histRow.CustomerNumber
AND maxes.LastUpdateSchedule = histRow.UpdatedSchedule
```